# How can I get the standard streams of my process without any library?

Tags: io, stream, compiler-construction

I'm writing a coding language of my own and I want to be able to create console applications, this means I need to be able to catch the standard streams of me process.

Can anyone give me any insight into how this is done in other languages?
For example, how does the Console class in C# work behind the covers? Or what does cout in C++ compile to?

Any insight would help, I don't have a solid lead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no portable solution without a library. Indeed, the point of the standard C I/O library is to provide a portable solution.

Each platform will also have its own libraries (for the various supported languages), which you could use if your compiler can produce anappropriate calling sequence.

The existence of the three standard streams (input, output and error output) is, in part, an artifact of the standard C library but there is usually an obvious translation from the platform's native interface.

For example, the Posix interface, in which every I/O stream is referenced with a small integer, called the "file descriptor" (fd), reserves fds 0, 1 and 2 for the three standard streams. Posix shells arrange for these fds to be correctly associated when they initiate a console application.

Windows has a different mechanism, which you can probably read about in the Windows documentation. (The shell interface is very different.)

And so on.

Comment: I may have explained myself incorrectly. I'm writing the compiler in C# so I could just define some keywords that are translated directly to the C# console class, but given that this is a practice project I would rather not do that. This is what I mean when a say I don't want to use a library.